# What is the purpose of runtimeChunk?

Tags: webpack

[optimization.runtimeChunk](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/optimization/#optimizationruntimechunk) what is the purpose of runtime chunk? What purpose does it serve? Does it make sense to use it if I am building library?

Answer (score 1):

in this image i have 3 file which is print.js,weirdRuntimeChunk,index.js
and I set the optimization.runtimeChunk = 'multiple' which will run 3 times because they have their own runtime not like an optimization.runtimeChunk = 'single' which is only have single runtime.
print.js and weirdRuntime do not have code inside. and in index.js i `console.log(this)` which will run 3 times because we have 3 runtimechunk generated.
[image]

```
// the output of index.js
console.log(this)
```

[image]

also webpack warned us about this behavior [reference](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/optimization/#optimizationruntimechunk)
[image]

Comment: also the purpose of this runtimeChunk is to get the single runtime of each chunks.